# Error consulta de Fechas SQLServer

Tags: select, sql-server-2017

Buenas estoy tengo una base de datos de SQLServer 2019 en la que no consigo hacer funcionar ninguna de las siguientes consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM minutal WHERE Fecha BETWEEN '2020-03-05 12:42:00.377' and '2020-03-05 12:50:00.377'
 SELECT * FROM minutal WHERE Fecha = '2020-03-05 12:42:00.377'
```

Es un campo DATETIME normal, he ejecutado la consulta sin problemas en una base de datos igual en un SQLServer mas antiguo, el problema me viene al ejecutarla en este SQL2017. No se si tengo el error en la sintaxis o en el formato o donde, hay conexión con la base de datos y puedo obtener la tabla entera con un

```
SELECT * FROM minutal
```

Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrias montar la foto de los datos de la tabla, y de la estructura de datos

Comment: la he modificado. Gracias.

Comment: La diferencia con la que tienes que sacarlo es de minutos? o simplemente es una diferencia de dos fechas?

Comment: La diferencia es de minutos

Comment: ¿Qué error te da lanzar esas dos consultas? He hecho una breve reproducción de estos datos en SQL Server 2017 y me funciona correctamente.

Comment: Aquí tienes un ejemplo con las consultas funcionando correctamente: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7f799/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás sufriendo un problema con el lenguaje del sistema (y por eso las pruebas que expuse en los comentarios funcionaban correctamente). Cuando se selecciona el lenguaje español el orden del mes y día se altera porque [los campos `DATETIME` no cumplen con las normas **ANSI** o **ISO 8601**](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#ansi-and-iso-8601-compliance):

> **datetime** no es compatible con ANSI o ISO 8601.

¿Qué significa esto? Que su contenido varía al mostrarse (dependiendo de la localización de tu cliente) e insertarse o buscarse dependiendo de la localización de la base de datos y/o conexión ([ver ejemplo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/11204)):

```
SET LANGUAGE Spanish;

CREATE TABLE minutal(
  Fecha DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO minutal (
  Fecha
) VALUES (
  '2020-03-05 12:48:00.377'
), (
  '2020-03-05 12:49:00.377'
), (
  '2020-03-05 12:42:00.377'
), (
  '2020-03-05 12:59:00.377'
), (
  '2020-03-05T12:48:00.377'
), (
  '2020-03-05T12:49:00.377'
), (
  '2020-03-05T12:42:00.377'
), (
  '2020-03-05T12:59:00.377'
);
```

Ahora listamos el contenido de la tabla:

```
SELECT * FROM minutal;
        Fecha
2020-05-03T12:48:00.377Z
2020-05-03T12:49:00.377Z
2020-05-03T12:42:00.377Z
2020-05-03T12:59:00.377Z
2020-03-05T12:48:00.377Z
2020-03-05T12:49:00.377Z
2020-03-05T12:42:00.377Z
2020-03-05T12:59:00.377Z
```

Como podemos ver, las primeras inserciones en la tabla no seguían el estándar de [fechas juntas **ISO 8601**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Fechas_y_horas_conjuntas), por lo que se insertaron adaptando el contenido de la cadena a la localización del idioma español, tomando el primer número (3) como el día (y no el mes) y el segundo número (5) como el mes (y no el día).

Si realizamos las inserciones en **ISO 8601** (en cuanto separamos la fecha de la hora con una letra **T** SQL Server entiende que está en ese formato) nos aseguramos que SQL Server no tendrá dudas del formato de fecha y lo insertará correctamente.

Así que lo que estabas viendo en tu listado era año/día/mes y no año/mes:

[image: Listado de tabla]

Por eso tus consultas de búsqueda no encontraban nada, porque no estabas buscando en el mes y día adecuado.

---

**Resumen**

- Procura usar **SIEMPRE** fechas en formato **ISO 8601** tanto en inserciones `INSERT` como en cláusulas `WHERE`. Eso evitará cualquier ambigüedad en la interpretación de la fecha.
- Para ver las fechas en formato **ISO 8601** y evitar ambigüedades en su lectura, usa `CONVERT(VARCHAR(24), Fecha, 127)`. Donde [el código `127` se corresponde con **ISO 8601**](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(24), Fecha, 127) Fecha FROM minutal
```

Answer (score 1):

Segun lo que dices, cuando se realizan los filtro de esa manera lo mas probable es que te falle entre el intervalo de tiempo, yo lo que te sugeriria es que lo hagas de la siguiente forma,

```
 SELECT * FROM minutal WHERE year(Fecha)=2020 and month(Fecha)='03' and day(Fecha)='05'    BETWEEN year(Fecha)=2020 and month(Fecha)='03' and day(Fecha)='31'
```

intentalo a si y pues mira si te da

Comment: Buenas, la consulta sin el between si que funciona: SELECT * FROM minutal WHERE year(Fecha)=2020 and month(Fecha)='03' and day(Fecha)='05' con el between da error, el tema es que necesito hacer funcionar la primera consulta o del estilo del formato, por que tengo una aplicación hecha en c# para el acceso a los datos, y sería un tostón cambiarlo todo...

Answer (score 1):

Acabe de probar con esto

```
SELECT * FROM minutal WHERE fecha BETWEEN '2020-03-05 12:52:00.213' and '2020-03-05 13:00:00.237'
```

Y me devolvio esto

```
2020-03-05 12:52:00.213 
2020-03-05 12:55:00.103 
2020-03-05 12:57:00.293 
2020-03-05 12:57:15.419 
2020-03-05 12:59:00.215
```

Intenta ponerlo a ver que te devuelve y me comentas

Comment: buenas no me devuelve nada, pongo la foto en la pregunta

Comment: Muy raro, porque tengo los mismos datos y a mi si me trae resultado

Answer (score 0):

resulta que sqlServer 2019 devuelve los datos de consulta con el siguiente formato:

```
 mm-dd-yyyy HH.mm.ss.fff
```

Me ha funcionado la consulta así:

```
SELECT * FROM minutal WHERE fecha BETWEEN '05-03-2020 12:52:00.213' and '05-03-2020 13:00:00.237'
```

aunque si tu copias el dato de la columna directamente te lo coje al revés

```
yyyy-mm-dd HH.mm.ss.fff
2020-03-05 12:57:00.220
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te respondo a esta solución que has optado y te explico en otra respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con la siguiente consulta

```
set dateformat ymd;
SELECT * FROM minutal WHERE Fecha >= '2020-03-05 12:42:00.377' and Fecha <= '2020-03-05 12:50:00.377'
```

Con el uso de parámetros que enviarías desde tu código, y por cuestiones de formato de fecha lo ideal es que en la consulta se dé formato a la fecha en SQL.
Por ejemplo:

```
set dateformat dmy;
SELECT * FROM minutal WHERE Fecha >= @inicio and Fecha <= @fin;
```

Esto suponiendo que tu formato en el código sea día, mes y año.